# Modifying a default MVC5 project to use a custom UserStore

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm tying to build a simple MVC application that replaces the EntityFramework persistence with one that reads/writes to/from an XML file.  I don't need anything fancy like roles or claims, I just need to make sure the user is authenticated.

From my research, I *think* I need to create a my own **UserStore** and modify the following code in IdentityConfig.cs to use this custom UserStore instead.  Is this the correct approach? TO me it seems like a classic dependency injection solution.  Create a new implementation of UserStore and inject that into the ApplicationUserManager.

```
   public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            ...
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I'm having trouble trying to create this custom UserStore, following the example from [MVC 5 Custom UserStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657487/mvc-5-custom-userstore) , specifcally

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<User> { }
```

I have no idea what type **User** is supposed to be.  I assume it's a class I need to create implementing a specific interface (I'm guessing IUser).  I've tried a couple dozen of variations for this unknown user type, but no matter what happens when I try to implement the following in IndentityCofig.us

```
        var us = new XmlUserStore<???>(someXmlDoc);
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(us);
```

I get a syntax error telling me that the non-generic type MyXmlStore cannot be used with type arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that should do it, basically implement a XmlUserStore and plug that in there, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that want to use an MVC5 application "out of the box" but only need a few users that you want to manually control, I made a complete sample application available at github:

```
git clone https://github.com/FutureTense/stackoverflow.com-questions-24315079-modifying-a-default-mvc5-project-to-use-a-custom-usersto
```

I basically created a new **UserStore** implementation that reads from an XML file.  I suggest you look at the diffs for each file to see what was changed in the original MVC application to use this new store.

The first commit is simply a default MVC5 application using EntityFramework as the persistence engine for Asp.Net identity credentials.  The second commit  adds a new project to the solution called **XmlUserStore** which will read user credentials from an Xml file.  **NOTE**:  This only *reads* credentials from the file.  The majority of the other interfaces will throw a "not implemented" exception.  Then I replaced the EF version of UserStore with the Xml version.

You could easily finish these stubs to have the entire credential system working with XML files, but as I only needed to read from the XML, this was good enough for my purposes.  Ideally you would also remove most of the AcccountController methods that aren't implemented.

The authentication file is in ~/App_Data/Users.xml and you can manually add/remove users (with roles) there.  Yes, it's not very secure (you should prevent browser access to this file), but this is just an example after all.  Also the passwords are stored in clear-text.  You can change this by modifying the **PasswordHasher** class to use whatever hash implementation you desire.