# Custom AspNet.Identity UserStore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I am implementing my own custom UserStore for web api. I would like to know where I can find the source code for AspNet.Identity's UserStore because I don't intend on changing it completely but I mean to introduce additional behavior that is related to my problem space.

Comment: What exactly you are planning to change ? You can find the source code here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity .Couple of examples with customized userstore are here http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider and https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo

Comment: Version 2 of Identity is here: http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for the interface and the class from the asp.net core on GitHub

Interface:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IUserStore.cs

Class:
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat/UserStore.cs

I am not sure you will find a documentation for it, but it is not hard to understand. You can always ask for an explanation here on Stackoverflow.

You can also look at this question for a stackoverflow member who is doing something like what you are doing now. 
[MVC 5 Custom UserStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657487/mvc-5-custom-userstore?rq=1)

Comment: Github hosts Identity v3 that is working with .Net Core. V2 of identity is here: http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the identity architecture [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-aspnet-core-identity-architecture)

You can customize stores if you are planning to change the way of data accessing.
For example you don't want to use default EF and would like to control your own way to access data from AspNetUser table.
You can implement only those interfaces that you are using. Options are [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-the-user-store)

But if you are planning to update some logic during the Login, you should customize Identity Manager. You will need to implement Custom SignInManager for that.