# IPrincipal Dependency Injection in MVC5

Tags: c#, authentication, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

In another stackoverflow question [MVC5 IoC and Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339810/mvc-5-ioc-and-authentication) the first answer states the author uses Dependency Injection to inject the IPrincipal.  I would love to do this for my assemblers so that I don't have to pass the current user (IPrincipal) from the controller.

Can anyone give an example of how to use DI to inject the IPrincipal in C# MVC5? Below is the IoC I first want to implement it in.  Added after first answer given.

```
    public class ViewModelAssemblersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IAspNetUserAssembler>()
                .ImplementedBy<AspNetUserAssembler>());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Castle Windsor, it's something like:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IPrincipal>()
  .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
  .UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.User));
```

Comment: Just a side note that the User.Identity.GetUserId() method is an extension method and you must include the below using to access it.

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

Comment: Do you know how would it be for Simple Injector?

Answer (score 6):

Its going to be dependent on your IoC container... for me, I use Unity, and in my container registration I'm able to do the following:

```
container.RegisterType<IPrincipal>(new InjectionFactory(u => HttpContext.Current.User));
```

Using the `InjectionFactory`, unity will execute the lambda to return the current `HttpContext.Current.User` at the time of constructor injection. I'm also able to use the same type of registration in my non web applications, instead referencing the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Comment: I'd rename `u` to `c` because it stands for `container` :)

Comment: This looks like great info, but my project is using Windsor